# Kendo Ui combobox - set default value

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I successfully filled my combobox. But now I'm trying to set default value for combobox. For example let's say third value from source. This is my input and datasource:

```
<script>
viewModel.dataSourceType = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/api/Type/Get",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        id: "Id",
        data: "Data",
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {}
        }
    }
});
```

```
<input id="type"
 data-role="combobox"
 data-value-primitive="true"
 data-auto-bind="true"
 data-text-field="Name"
 data-value-field="Id"
 data-bind="value: model.Id, source: dataSourceType">
```

It's probably really easy but I'm strugling with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you look for the [index](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-index) configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problem is in your `model` definition, i.e. what you are binding to the combobox.

According with your definition your JavaScript should be something like:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        ...
    }
});

var model = new kendo.observable({
    dataSourceType: dataSource,
    model : { Id: 2 }
});
kendo.bind($("#type"), model);
```

Where `2` is the value that you want as default (initial) value.

Realize that I have had to declare an extra `model` for `Id` since you say in your `data-bind` definition that `value` is `model.Id`.

Maybe you wanted to say:

```
var model = new kendo.observable({
    dataSourceType: dataSource,
    Id: 2
});
kendo.bind($("#type"), model);
```

And then you should define the HTML as:

```
<input id="type"
    data-role="combobox"
    data-value-primitive="true"
    data-auto-bind="true"
    data-text-field="Name"
    data-value-field="Id"
    data-bind="value: Id, source: dataSourceType">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
      }
    }
  });
  var model = new kendo.observable({
    dataSourceType: dataSource,
    Id: 2
  });
  kendo.bind($("#cbox"), model);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="cbox"
       data-role="combobox"
       data-value-primitive="true"
       data-auto-bind="true"
       data-text-field="ProductName"
       data-value-field="ProductID"
       data-bind="value: Id, source: dataSourceType">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve like this.

```
var combobox = $("#kendoitems").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.select(1);
```

you need to pass the index value to select(index).

Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/NdPze/63/